# Use of PCA results as input to XGboost model throwing an error: Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different

Tags: r, pca, xgboost

I use PCA on my divided train dataset and project the test dataset to the results after removing irrelevant columns.

```
data <- read.csv('bottom10.csv')
set.seed(1)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(data$cuisine, p = .8)[[1]]
dataTrain <- data[,-1][inTrain,][,-1]
dataTest <- data[,-1][-inTrain,][,-1]
cuisine.pca <- prcomp(dataTrain[,-1])
```

Then I extract the first 500 components and project the test dataset.

```
traincom <- cuisine.pca$x[,1:500]
testcom <- scale(dataTest[,-1], cuisine.pca$center) %*% cuisine.pca$rotation
```

Then I transfer the labels into integer, and combine components and labels into xgbDMatrix form.

```
label_train <- as.integer(dataTrain$cuisine) - 1
label_test <- as.integer(dataTest$cuisine) - 1
xgb_train <- xgb.DMatrix(data = traincom, label = label_train)
xgb_test <- xgb.DMatrix(data = testcom, label = label_test)
```

Then I build the xgboost model as

```
xgb.fit <- xgboost(cuisine~., data = xgb_train, nrounds = 40, num_class = 10, early_stopping_rounds = 5)
```

And after I run this, there is a warning but the training can still run.

```
xgboost: label will be ignored
```

I can predict the train dataset using the model but when I try to predict test dataset there will be an error.

```
xgb_pred <- predict(xgb.fit, newdata = xgb_train)
sum(label_train == xgb_pred)/length(label_train)
xgb_pred <- predict(xgb.fit, newdata = xgb_test, rescale = T)

Error in predict.xgb.Booster(xgb.fit, newdata = xgb_test, rescale = T) : 
  Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different!
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: Try `names(xgb_train)` and `names(xgb_test)`. I think the error is coming due to mismatch of column names of train and test data.

Comment: Hi, the results are both NULL. And if I print both the xgb_train and xgb_test, the results are "xgb.DMatrix  dim: 5742 x 500  info: label  colnames: yes" and "xgb.DMatrix  dim: 1431 x 3578  info: label  colnames: yes". I found out the reason why the error is happening. I can only predict 500 test data, as I extract 500 components from PCA. I wonder if there are some solutions so I can predict all test data all once. Thank you very much.

Comment: Then try `colnames(xgb_train)` and `colnames(xgb_test)`

Comment: Thanks, the results are PC1, PC2, ..., PC500, so I can only predict the 500 test data.

Comment: You do the PCA first with your data, then you divide the PCA output into train and test sets. If you can provide the data I can try it.

Comment: It is a school assignment and the professor requires us to divide first and only project the test data to PCA results. Thank you anyway. :)